# Several questions about my VPS - ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, postfix, vps

I noticed some suspicious actions on my vps and I wanted to understand them a bit more.

postfix: I saw a lot of actions using postfix in mail.log so I shut postfix down and saw

> Jan  9 22:58:28 domain postfix/postfix-script[6035]: stopping the
>   Postfix mail system Jan  9 22:58:28 domain postfix/master[791]:
>   terminating on signal 15  Jan  9 22:58:28 domain
>   postfix/postfix-script[6045]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is not
>   running  Jan  9 22:58:30 domain postfix/postfix-script[6119]:
>   warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/./sasl/sasl_passwd.db  Jan  9
>   22:58:30 domain postfix/postfix-script[6120]: warning: not owned by
>   root: /etc/postfix/./sasl/sasl_passwd  Jan  9 22:58:30 domain 
>   postfix/postqueue[6162]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing
>   queue directly

after that it got quiet. I have no need for postfix so can I just keep it down or will it affect something else I'm unaware of? Assuming the log is calm now, can I be sure no one can use my vps for sending emails?

Another thing:
In webmin I see 43 users! root is obvious. Other 42 include (for example) deamon, dovecot, tomcat, list, irc... how can I know which I can delete? At first I disabled everything except for root but then I realized my tomcat shut down, so I re-enabled everything and start tomcat again. Was it related? Do I need to keep certain users and others I can remove?

Last thing, from auth.log

```
Jan  9 23:22:20 domain su[15114]: Successful su for domain by root
Jan  9 23:22:20 domain su[15114]: + ??? root:domain 
Jan  9 23:22:20 domain su[15114]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user domain by (uid=0)
Jan  9 23:22:20 domain su[15114]: pam_systemd(su:session): Failed to create session: Maximum number of sessions (8192) reached, refusing further sessions.
Jan  9 23:22:20 domain su[15114]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user domain 
Jan  9 23:24:47 domain sshd[15645]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=111.231.50.90  user=root
Jan  9 23:24:49 domain sshd[15645]: Failed password for root from 111.231.50.90 port 54480 ssh2
Jan  9 23:24:49 domain sshd[15645]: Received disconnect from 111.231.50.90 port 54480:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan  9 23:24:49 domain sshd[15645]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 111.231.50.90 port 54480 [preauth]
Jan  9 23:27:21 domain su[16754]: Successful su for domain by root
Jan  9 23:27:21 domain su[16754]: + ??? root:domain 
Jan  9 23:27:21 domain su[16754]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user domain by (uid=0)
Jan  9 23:27:21 domain su[16754]: pam_systemd(su:session): Failed to create session: Maximum number of sessions (8192) reached, refusing further sessions.
Jan  9 23:27:21 domain su[16754]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user domain 
Jan  9 23:29:12 domain sshd[17078]: Invalid user ay from 164.132.57.16 port 42111
Jan  9 23:29:12 domain sshd[17078]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jan  9 23:29:12 domain sshd[17078]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=164.132.57.16
Jan  9 23:29:14 domain sshd[17078]: Failed password for invalid user ay from 164.132.57.16 port 42111 ssh2
Jan  9 23:29:14 domain sshd[17078]: Received disconnect from 164.132.57.16 port 42111:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan  9 23:29:14 domain sshd[17078]: Disconnected from invalid user ay 164.132.57.16 port 42111 [preauth]
Jan  9 23:30:30 domain sshd[17295]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=190.195.131.249  user=root
Jan  9 23:30:32 domain sshd[17295]: Failed password for root from 190.195.131.249 port 40859 ssh2
Jan  9 23:30:32 domain sshd[17295]: Received disconnect from 190.195.131.249 port 40859:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan  9 23:30:32 domain sshd[17295]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 190.195.131.249 port 40859 [preauth]
Jan  9 23:32:23 domain su[18247]: Successful su for domain by root
Jan  9 23:32:23 domain su[18247]: + ??? root:domain 
Jan  9 23:32:23 domain su[18247]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user domain by (uid=0)
Jan  9 23:32:23 domain su[18247]: pam_systemd(su:session): Failed to create session: Maximum number of sessions (8192) reached, refusing further sessions.
Jan  9 23:32:23 domain su[18247]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user domain 
Jan  9 23:36:13 domain sshd[19029]: Accepted password for root from 87.71.134.34 port 61633 ssh2
Jan  9 23:36:13 domain sshd[19029]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan  9 23:36:13 domain sshd[19029]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: Maximum number of sessions (8192) reached, refusing further sessions.
```

A specific line I've noticed

```
Successful su for domain by root
```

What does it mean? The above log is "ok" and just means bad people are trying to connect to my vps or does it mean they actually succeeded and are using it for their benefits?

edit: I just checked "recorded logins" and I do see only root in the list. So what is all I see at the above log?

There are also a lot of groups. Trying to delete them (except root), gives me the following: You are not allowed to delete system groups (those with a GID less than or equal to 10).

in htop I see the following process 18h17:17 /lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 28 where 18h is marked in red. What does it mean?

After some time of quiet, I saw this in mail.log

```
Jan 10 00:11:08 domain dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 4 secs): user=<>, rip=185.142.236.35, lip=93.188.167.48, TLS, session=</9Vp9r2bSKS5juwj>
Jan 10 00:11:09 domain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=185.142.236.35, lip=93.188.167.48, TLS: SSL_read() failed: error:140940F5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:unexpected record, session=<PIx39r2bVK25juwj>
Jan 10 00:11:13 domain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, rip=185.142.236.35, lip=93.188.167.48, TLS: SSL_read() syscall failed: Connection reset by peer, session=<eayw9r2b1rS5juwj>
Jan 10 00:11:13 domain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=185.142.236.35, lip=93.188.167.48, TLS, session=<Ibyx9r2b3rW5juwj>
Jan 10 00:11:13 domain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=185.142.236.35, lip=93.188.167.48, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:142090FC:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:unknown protocol, session=<rgW19r2bxLa5juwj>
Jan 10 00:11:14 domain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=185.142.236.35, lip=93.188.167.48, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:1420918C:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:version too low, session=<BwO69r2bkre5juwj>
Jan 10 00:11:14 domain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=185.142.236.35, lip=93.188.167.48, TLS, session=<rnzD9r2bqLi5juwj>
Jan 10 00:11:15 domain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, rip=185.142.236.35, lip=93.188.167.48, TLS, session=<C/LJ9r2b7Lm5juwj>
Jan 10 00:11:15 domain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=185.142.236.35, lip=93.188.167.48, TLS, session=<gLXR9r2b1rq5juwj>
Jan 10 00:11:16 domain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, rip=185.142.236.35, lip=93.188.167.48, TLS, session=</CnZ9r2bAry5juwj>
Jan 10 00:11:16 domain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=185.142.236.35, lip=93.188.167.48, TLS, session=<Qofg9r2b8ry5juwj>
Jan 10 00:11:16 domain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=185.142.236.35, lip=93.188.167.48, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher, session=<mcXi9r2bzr25juwj>
```

Thanks